# Pandas Assign Lambda Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, python-datetime

I have a DataFrame which has an open time and a close time and I am trying to calculate the difference in milliseconds.

My code is currently like this

```
df = df.assign(Latency=lambda d: d.CloseTimeStamp - d.CreationTimeStamp)
df.Latency = df.apply(lambda d: d.Latency.total_seconds() * 1000., axis=1)
```

However, I'd like to know why I can't do as a one-liner like so

```
df = df.assign(Latency=lambda d: (d.CloseTimeStamp - d.CreationTimeStamp).total_seconds() * 1000.)
```

When I try the latter I get `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'`

Comment: How does it work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Total seconds is inside the `.dt` attribute, so this should work:

```
df = df.assign(Latency=lambda d: (d.CloseTimeStamp - d.CreationTimeStamp).dt.total_seconds() * 1000.)
```

Having said so, there's no need for a lambda function:

```
df = df.assign(Latency=(df.CloseTimeStamp - df.CreationTimeStamp).dt.total_seconds() * 1000.)
```

is much faster.

A further remark on efficiency: `df.assign()` builds a completely new dataframe object; if you're intending to assign this object back onto `df`, you're better off modifying `df` in-place:

```
df['Latency'] = (df.CloseTimeStamp - df.CreationTimeStamp).dt.total_seconds() * 1000.
```

Answer (score 2):

Need `.dt` accessor, because working with `datetime Series`, `.dt` is omit if `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df.assign(Latency=lambda d: (d.CloseTimeStamp -  d.CreationTimeStamp).dt.total_seconds() * 1000.)
```

Solution without lambda:

```
df = df.assign(Latency=(df.CloseTimeStamp - df.CreationTimeStamp).dt.total_seconds() * 1000.)
```

...and solution without `assign`:

```
df['Latency'] = (df.CloseTimeStamp - df.CreationTimeStamp).dt.total_seconds() * 1000.
```